# Coudn't Flash to a softdevice

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

I am using nRF5 SDK to flash a softdevice pca10001 s110, and when ever I am using make `flash_softdevice` it shows the below error line :

```
Flashing: s130_nrf51_2.0.0_softdevice.hex
nrfjprog --program ../../../../../../components/softdevice/s130/hex/s130_nrf51_2.0.0_softdevice.hex -f nrf51 --chiperase
make: execvp: nrfjprog: Permission denied
Makefile:245: recipe for target 'flash_softdevice' failed
make: *** [flash_softdevice] Error 127
```

Comment: Improve your tags (add more relevant tags) for better access to more help. Also make sure this is a **programming** question not just a hardware issue (since not "code related" issues are off-topic on this forum).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the user with which you try to execute `nrfjprog` does not have the rights to do so. Try to make it runnable:

`sudo chmod a+x <path-to-nrfjprog>/nrfjprog`

That should make it runnable for all users.